# compiler error : wasted space

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Aat the end of compiling a project, I got this weird compiler error:

```
"llvm_transformed_context_ini.c", line 3198: warning: loop not entered at top
"llvm_transformed_context_ini.c", line 3218: warning: loop not entered at top
"llvm_transformed_context_ini.c", line 3237: warning: statement not reached
"llvm_transformed_context_ini.c", line 3248: warning: loop not entered at top
"llvm_transformed_context_ini.c", line 3268: warning: loop not entered at top
"llvm_transformed_context_ini.c", line 3287: warning: statement not reached
op: 2, val: 0
"llvm_transformed_context_ini.c", line 3291: compiler error: wasted space: 1047036660
```

The  line is the last one located in the .c file and has nothing written on it. I tried to delete the line but that didn't fix the problem.

****_17th_september_EDITED TEXT:

You can download it from [here](https://www.asuswebstorage.com/navigate/s?u=GY4IFVNJAL)

Can anyone explain it to me ??

Thanks,

Amir

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: What compiler is this,and what platform\?

Comment: I would try to use a different compiler (GCC perhaps), or a different version of your compiler. And we can't help more if we don't know the exact version of your system and your compiler (and perhaps also the linker).

Comment: it is actually HP-Vex 32 bit compiler for .c codes. and since I am using it for a research purpose, I have to stick to this one.

Comment: That sounds like an internal compiler error. It means there's a bug in the compiler itself. You should submit a detailed report, including your source files, to the compiler vendor (and then pray that they have good support).

Comment: In the project, I got 25-30 .c files, but this error was for the end of 5th file.

Comment: So you think there won't be any hopes ?!! :||||

Comment: There is no hope of an answer here whatsoever until you deign to post the code on line 3411 and surrounding it.

Comment: I am sending you the file, you can download it from the edited question text ;) thanks

Comment: You could try to find the problem by cutting down the file. Delete parts and recompile, if the error remains keep deleting. If not restore what you deleted and delete something else. Chances are that the problem is triggered by a relatively simple construct. Once you have found it, you can try to remove it from the original source file.

Comment: @Joe: As I might have mentioned, the compiler is Vex 3.43, the platform is ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure will it help or not, but you can try to remove all dummy "do..while" loops. To do that you should remove all lines that contains phrase ".. syntactic loop .." in comment.

For example:

```
  do {     /* Syntactic loop 'bb172' to make GCC happy */ <<-- remove this line
llvm_cbe_bb172:
  llvm_cbe_tmp__425 = *(&llvm_cbe_model_number);
  llvm_cbe_tmp__426 = *(&llvm_cbe_i);
  llvm_cbe_tmp__427 = *(&llvm_cbe_j);
  llvm_cbe_tmp__428 = *(&llvm_cbe_i);
  llvm_cbe_tmp__429 = *(&llvm_cbe_j);
  llvm_cbe_tmp__430 = *(&llvm_cbe_tc);
  llvm_cbe_tmp__431 = *(&llvm_cbe_qp);
  biari_init_context(llvm_cbe_tmp__431, ((&(*((&(*((&llvm_cbe_tmp__430->field7))).array[((signed int )llvm_cbe_tmp__428)]))).array[((signed int )llvm_cbe_tmp__429)])), ((&(*((&(*((&(*((&INIT_ABS_P.array[((signed int )llvm_cbe_tmp__425)]))).array[((signed int )llvm_cbe_tmp__426)]))).array[((signed int )llvm_cbe_tmp__427)]))).array[((signed int )0u)])));
  llvm_cbe_tmp__432 = *(&llvm_cbe_j);
  *(&llvm_cbe_j) = (((unsigned int )(((unsigned int )llvm_cbe_tmp__432) + ((unsigned int )1u))));
  llvm_cbe_tmp__433 = *(&llvm_cbe_j);
  if ((((signed int )llvm_cbe_tmp__433) <= ((signed int )4u))) {
    goto llvm_cbe_bb172;
  } else {
    goto llvm_cbe_bb174;
  }

  } while (1); /* end of syntactic loop 'bb172' */ <<-- remove this line
```

There are a lot of "goto" labels in this code. Probably your current compiler is not able to resolve goto's in loops.

Comment: Thanks, but the point is I have these project being compiled by llvm with some specific optimization configs and then compiled it with Vex. so the reason you see all these mess is the optimizations made by llvm. Don't think I can remove those :|

Comment: It's up to you. I would have tried it, since comments says something about GCC syntax, not about LLVM or Vex.

Comment: if I wanna separate these tables in separate .c file and compile them separately by fixing the include, do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by tables.. If you mean large data structures defined in first half of file - you can move current code (definitions) to `Tables.c`, gather all declarations in `Tables.h` and include `Tables.h` in both `.c` files.